# Why do Shias do things differently?

Tags: practical-islam, shiism, shia-sunni

What I understand the reason for separation was a dispute over the succession of the Caliphate (I could be wrong), how did this turn into Shias doing things (praying, adhan etc.) that differ from Sunnis.

Of course what I know could be wrong, if so please correct me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salaam brother,

Actually there aren't many differences between the Shi'a and Sunni school of thought...

The only differences that are there are in Jurisprudence.. and even then they are minute...

Even within Sunni School of thought you have people with different Jurisprudence.. There are 4 Sunni madhabs (Hanafi, Sha'fi, Maliki, Hanbali). The Dean of Al-Azhar University (Biggest Islamic University) Said that: "The 5th Madhab in Islam is Ja'fri(Shia)"

Having difference of opinion in Jurisprudence isn't that big of a deal...  It doesn't mean if a person prays differently that he is not muslims anymore...

Most of the Ahle-Sunnat pray with their hands folded... But the Sunni Maliki's Pray with their hands on their sides, just like the Shia..

So it's not such a big deal... every school of thought, madhab, has their own proves and hadith to prove what they do is correct... we cannot say one is right and the other is wrong.

Comment: Shia is Not from the Ja'fri Madhab do a deep study otherwise they will also be considered as sunni and considered among the 5th madhab why all others scholars are considered as sunni. Imam jafar never gone against the decisions of companion of prophets.

Comment: @ali786, There are numerous hadiths from Imam al-Sadiq indicating that his holiness only recognized Prophet's purified Ahl al-Bayt as legitimate Imams of the Ummah. And if he hadn't opposed the caliphs there would've been no reason for the suppression of his followers and other members of Ahl al-Bayt by Abbassid and Umayyad caliphs that viewed the Shia Imams as a threat to their governments and thus ultimately murdered them all.

Comment: Please have a look at these posts for learning about historical conditions of the Imams. http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12640/ and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16977/

Comment: @infatuated, had a look to the mentioned links as you submitted, they seems useful. Jazak Allah Khaira.

Comment: We are not a site for preaching: Answers are expected to be clear and focussed and directly answer the question asked, not for inserting tangential personal opinions.

Answer (score 3):

Most of Islamic jurisprudence is based on two sources, the Qur'an and hadiths, this is the same between Sunnis and Shi'i.  Even when both follow the same Qur'an, there are a lot of different opinions regarding the hadiths.

Many Shi'a narrations are considered unreliable by Sunnis and many Sunni narrations are considered unreliable by Shi'i. One famous example would be the case of Abu Hurayrah, who narrated over five thousand hadiths: Sunnis consider him a reliable source, Shi'ites do not, and his case is not unique.  On the other hand, Shi'ite hadith sciences give far more weight to those narrations transmitted through the Ahl-ul Bayt than do Sunnis, often taking narrations by the Imams as indisputably authentic even when there is no chain between the Imam and the prophet that would meet Sunni criteria.

As a result the body of hadith literature that Shi'i use for jurisprudence can be similar to Sunnis in many cases, but vastly different in others. Because of these differences and over fourteen centuries of study and rulings based on these differences, both groups have diverged significantly.

Comment: No Sunnis wouldn't consider any hadith's as unreliable if it's directly narrated by companion's of prophets.Can you consider giving such an examples.

Comment: @ali786 Who said anything about that?  I only said that not all Shi'ite narrations are accepted by Sunnis, please read my answer carefully.

Answer (score 0):

*The two answers here didn't really answer the question*

The notion that **shia** and **sunni** happened is because of dispute over the caliph is **wrong**. The only dispute that happened is between *Muhajreen* and *Ansar* on whether to choose a caliph from *Muhajreen* or caliph from *Ansar*. *Check: "[`Umar's statement on the doctrine of succession in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7250/umars-statement-on-the-doctrine-of-succession-in-islam/7311#7311)"*

Shia term came after 41 years from the death of the prophet (specifically after the death of Ali). The term shia was referring to a **sunni political movement** that preferred Al-Hassan to be in power instead of Muwayah.

Then, this term started to evolve and many sects started coming out from the main shia/sunni movement. After 600 years from the death of Ali. Another shia sect called Twelever Shia came to existence that claimed Abu Baker, Umar and other companions stole the khilafah from Ali. This sect had their own hadiths, fiqh, and teachings. For more info:

---

- Is there a common book between **Shia** and **sunni** other than al-Quran. shia and sunni have different books of hadiths.

  Check "[What Islamic texts do the Sunni and Shia branches have in common?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7338/what-islamic-texts-do-the-sunni-and-shia-branches-have-in-common/7344#7344)" *and "[Why do the Shi'a have different hadiths?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/why-do-the-shia-have-different-hadiths)"*
- **Shia** believe the companions of the prophet (Abu Baker and Umar) killed Fatima and her son.

  *Check "[According to Shi'a Islam, did Fatimah (daughter of Prophet Muhammad) die naturally, or was she killed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5988/according-to-shia-islam-did-fatimah-daughter-of-prophet-muhammed-die-natural)" Here is the sunni view: "https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12520/885"*
- **Shia** say Abu Baker, Umar, And Othman are not going to paradise.

  *Check: "[Shia view about three righteous caliphs (Other than Ali R.A.)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5332/shia-view-about-three-righteous-caliphs-other-than-ali-r-a)"*
- **Shia** deny seeing allah on the day of judgment while sunni don't.

  *Check: "[Do Shi'ites deny seeing Allah on the Day of Judgement? If yes, Why?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/do-shiites-deny-seeing-allah-on-the-day-of-judgement-if-yes-why)"*
- **Sunni** believe no one can receive revelation after the prophet while **shia** believe the 12 Imams can receive revelations from allah.

  *Check [alisilam.org - how will Imam know time](http://www.al-islam.org/al-imam-al-mahdi-just-leader-humanity-ayatullah-ibrahim-amini/chapter-12-how-will-imam-know-time)*
- **Shia** believe the 12 Imams (Ali, Hassan, Hussien, etc...) are infallible

  *Check:"[Why do the Shi'as believe that their Imams can provide divine guidance?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/604/why-do-the-shias-believe-that-their-imams-can-provide-divine-guidance)"*
- **Shia** believe that the 12 Imams are better than all the prophets except Muhammed (PBUH).

  Check: "[What is the difference between a Prophet and an Imam according to Shi'ite theology?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2559/difference-between-a-prophet-and-an-imam-according-to-shiite-theology)"
- **Sunni** believe in Shura when choosing a successor after the prophet while **shia** believe Ali was chose by allah and hence, Abu Bkaer, Umar, and Othman stole the imamat from him.

  *Check: "[Why does Shi'a Islam differ so much regarding Abu Bakr, Omar and Othman, compared to Sunni teachings?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/961/why-does-shia-islam-differ-so-much-regarding-abu-bakr-omar-and-othman-compare)"*
- **Shia** allow Mutah (temp marriage), while **sunni** consider it Zina (adultery).

  check: "[How is Mutah different from prostitution (from a non-Muslim point of view)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16461/how-is-mutaa-different-from-prostitution-from-a-non-muslim-point-of-view)" and "[Why did Umar (RA) forbid Mutah (temporary marriage) after the death of the prophet?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13283/why-did-umar-ra-forbid-mutah-temporary-marriage-after-the-death-of-the-proph)"

and so much more that I cannot fit in this answer...

Comment: Unfortunately you didnt really answer the question. But you were able to provide a lot of Mis-Information! First of all there was no such thing as Sunni only Shia; Shia of Imam Ali and Shia of Muawiya. (2 Opposing sides)

Actually the Sunni School of thought and Twelver (Jafri) school of thought came later. In Shia who are also known as the Ja'fri get their jurisprudence from Imam Jafar-as-Sadiq. In Sunni you have Hanafi, Maliki, Sha'fi, Hanbali.. who get their Jurispudence from Imam Abu Hanifa, Imam Malik, Imam Sha'fi, Imam Ahmed ibn Hanbal all these people were students of Imam Jafar!!!!!!!!

Comment: Shia means "Follower" that is why they were called Shia of Imam Ali and Shia of Muaviya

Comment: @Sohaeb, I am Shia but never we say that Abu-Bakr has killed Fatima(S.A). And also we are not instead of Allah to judge who goes to the heaven and who goes to the hell!. And also I never heard in my denomination that the 12 Imams are better than all previous prophets. You have to be Shia to knows what is the real Shia not by listening to others. You made mistake just like me in my question about the successor, do you remember?

Comment: @Fatemeh, The shia belief is that Abu-Bakr was indirectly involved in the murder of Lady Fatima for he ordered Umar to demand all muslims allegiance for his caliphate and suppress anyone who refused to recognize him! Also, that the 12 Imams are higher in spiritual status over all non-Islamic Prophets is also [a definite and widely accepted shia belief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fourteen_Infallibles).

Comment: To OP: Shias describes themselves as [*Shia* (follower) of (The Purified) *Ahlulbayt* (Household)](http://www.al-islam.org/message-thaqalayn/vol2-n2-3/ahl-al-bayt-its-meaning-and-origin/ahlul-bayt-its-meaning-and-origin)and provide ample evidences from the Prophet's Purified Household in rejection of the legitimacy of the reign of the first three caliphs recognized by the so called Sunnis. They trace the conflict between Ahlulbayt and the early Caliphs to a much earlier point in history than the death of Uthman.

Comment: It started right from the aftermath of Prophet's death when some Prophet's companions appointed Abu Bakr as Prophet's successor contrary to Prophet's appointment of Ali Ibn Abi Talib as his only legitimate, divinely-appointed immediate successor.