# What do Shias mean by taqiyya?

Tags: shiism, taqiya

I heard that Shias use a word taqiyya, in the al-Kafi book by Kulayni Imam Sadiq is quoted as saying: ... taqiyya is my religion... (Reference: الكافي للكليني (329 هـ) الجزء2 صفحة219 باب التقية).

I didn't find English reference so I must give the Arabic one. So what exactly do Shias means by taqiyya and why it's so important to them to say it's my religion?

If it's hide fellings, Ammar ibn Yassir can use taqiya and dissimulate his true felling and save himself and his family, Bilal ElHabachi too, Ashab El Oukhdoud too *[surat 85]*, Jesus disciple who are killed too. So what I understand in general is that taqiya is used when you're afraid, so begin afraid you're ready to do anything to save yourself, do what's not in religion, lie, commit haram. So what it means to be passion, since you can just hide.

Is it more worth to lie or to face death with your believes if you're really religious and look the sake of ALLAH?? I want clarity please!!

> Cursed were the companions of the trench when they were sitting near
>   it And they, to what they were doing against the believers, were
>   witnesses. And they resented them not except because they believed in
>   Allah , the Exalted in Might, the Praiseworthy [85, 5-8]
>
> That is only Satan who frightens [you] of his supporters. So fear them
>   not, but fear Me, if you are [indeed] believers. [3,175]

`

Answer (score 3):

*The concept of taqiyyah means that a believer is allowed to hide his true belief when in danger.*

Taqiyyah is mentioned in three places in the holy Qur'an:

> **3:28** Let not the believers take the disbelivers as guardians instead
>   of the believers, and whoever does this will never be helped by Allah
>   in any way, unless you indeed fear danger from them.
>
> **16:106** Whoever disbelieved in Allah after his belief - except him who
>   is forced thereto and whose heart is at rest with faith.
>
> **40:28** And a believing man from Pharaoh's family who hid his faith.....

**The first person in Islam practicing taqiyyah was the Prophet himself when he kept his mission secret for three years to protect the message.**

He told his most prominent companion Ammar ibn Yassir to deny his faith in public again if he was to be tortured again.

Many prominent leaders of all schools of thought practiced taqiyyah on different occasions. (see Moustafa al-Qazwini, Inquiries about Shi'a Islam,p.58)

Comment: +1 for the statement "The concept of taqiyyah means that a believer is allowed to hide his true belief when in danger."
- now what might be added is what the definition of danger is (so people don't think they can hide whenever they feel they are in "danger").
good answer though.

Comment: danger or harm means here: being subjected to persecution, torture, killing on account of your belief.

Comment: @Kilise, I appreciate you who fairly admire the nice answer of Noor. God bless you for being fair and unbiased.

Comment: @Noor The explanation of the concept is very nice, as well as providing references from the Qur'an. But I was just wondering why it was named Taqiyyah since the closest word I could think of that is mentioned in the Qur'an (تقياً) means someone who is fearing of Allah (SWT) (The word was mentioned 3 times in Surat Maryam, verses 13,18, and 63)