# Can religious faith be suspended and dropped under certain situations according to Shia branch of Islam?

Tags: sunni, shiism, taqiya

I once saw some internet video discussing about essential differences between Sunni and Shia branches of Islam and I clearly remembered it mentioned Shia posits that one's religious faith (not the usual many different beliefs and knowledges) can be possibly suspended and dropped under certain situations such as imminent unavoidable harsh external causes or pressures while Sunnis don't accept such possibilities.

I tried to find the exact source on internet but with no luck. Is there anyone here with sufficient knowledge can help clarify this difference in more detail?

Comment: You are asking about Taqiya. See https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48243/ for an answer from a Sunni perspective.

Comment: @UmH thx for your quick guide, and indeed Taqiya is the term my question is referring to. However, after peruse your link, it seems this is almost a common topic under duress of both Sunni and Shia branches, yet my memory tells me it's claimed as one of the essential differences besides the more obvious ones, do you have any more insight on this? Is there something to do with the four companions especially Ammār ibn Yāsir following the prophet's Taqiya advice to avoid torture? Or is there a connection to the idea that one's true faith has to be born again metaphorically speaking?